# Why boxShadow can change the background color of the container?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm adding a `BoxShadow` to a `Container` so I add property `BoxShadow` and choose the color. But I found I changed the background color of the container at the same time. I can't find the reason. Though I have gotten that I can avoid this by adding property color in decoration, but I am really puzzle about it. Below is the code segment.

```
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
//when I remove this line, background color will change with the BoxShadow color
          color: StatisticColor.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: StatisticColor.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
              spreadRadius: 3,
              blurRadius: 3,
              offset: Offset(0, 0), // changes position of shadow
            ),
          ],
          border: Border.all(
            color: StatisticColor.grey,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
        ),
```

Comment: the problem seems to be from StatisticColor. Can you post your StatisticColor code

Comment: StatisticColor is a class that contains all the colors I need in the page I'm drawing, and the problem occurs when I remove that line.

Comment: try replacing StatisticColor with Colors check if it works

Comment: I have tried it, but problem still occurs. I'm sure there is not the reason with the class statisticColor class since it's just class contains several colors.@Uni

Comment: Im not sure why now. Sorry @byhuang1998, I can't help you here.

Comment: it's OK, bro. I can figure out it by adding the property color inside decoration. Maybe it's about the bottom layer principle of the boxDecoration.@Uni

Comment: Oh wait. I thought it didn't work even if the color property is defined. Do you want me to write an answer why its not working when color property is not defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `BoxShadow` to a Container without any color property defined will change how the `Container` looks like. By default, the color of a `Container` is set to transparent. `BoxShadow` adds a shadow effect on the edges of the `Container`. `Offsetting` it will make the `BoxShadow` move its x and y-position. That is why you see that the background color of the `Container` change when adding `BoxShadow`. Also, I would recommend using [Card](https://material.io/develop/flutter/components/cards). It is easier to add shadows to a widget using it and it adds a small `BorderRadius` to the widget. Here is an example:

```
Card(
 elevation:5, //Optional, this intensifies the shadow applied
 child: MyWidget()
)
```

Comment: Can you explained more clearly why the whole container background color changed with the boxShadow color.

Comment: The color changes because by default, the color of a Container is transparent (透明). BoxShadow will add shadow to your Container. Since the Container is transparent, the shadow can be seen. Also, try using Card, its way easier to make good looking shadows with it.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much. Class Card may be bettor choice.

Comment: Good Luck. Card would be better here.